# MySQL can't start, ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file

Tags: mysql, macos

My System is MacOS Sierra, I download mysql-5.7.18-macos10.12-x86_64.dmg from the official website. After installing it, I found that I can't start MySQL.

I type the command **"sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start"** on the terminal, but it report an error **. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/*.pid).**

Do anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: When you install from the official website, there is usually a Start/Stop application in "System Preferences" added. Besides that, does the directory exist where it tries to find the pid?

Comment: I try to start from the System Preferences, but there is no response. Yes, there exists a directory that it tries to find the pid.